# How to check if a non-string value exists in a record set generated from GROUP?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables,

```
-- table of selected_courses
student_id  course_id
1           11
1           12
1           13
2           11
2           12
3           12
3           13
4           11

-- table of students
student_id  name
1           Adam
2           Bill
3           Calvin
4           David

-- table of courses
course_id   name
11          math
12          physics
13          chemistry
```

I would like to find those students who selected both physics(12) and chemistry(13), generally, in this case they should be Adam and Calvin.

Generally, I can get each student's course records by grouping

```
select * from selected_courses group by student_id;
```

then how can I find out if both 12 and 13 are in the student's group?

BTW, I am using mysql.

Comment: What have you tried in your join to do this yourself? Looks like you're just asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation

```
  select student_id from 
  selected_courses a
  where course_id in (12,13)
  group by student_id
  having count(distinct course_id)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
select student_id, course_id
from tablename a where exists 
  (select 1 from tablename b where a.student_id=b.student_id and course_id in (12,13) having count(distinct course_id)=2)
```